# Can UITableViews have static content if they're in their own xib file, and not a Storyboard?

Tags: uitableview, uistoryboard

When I make a new UITableViewController and click on the UITableView in the accompanying .xib file, I see this:

[image: UITableView in a XIB file]

Notice the "Table View" section of the properties on the right.  Specifically, there is no place to pick the 'Content' as Dynamic Prototypes, or Static Content, as with a UITableView in a UIStoryboard (below).

[image: UITableView properties in a storyboard]

What gives?  I can't think of any reason why these features would be Storyboard-only, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is a Storyboard only feature for now.

Hopefully Apple will make this very useful feature available to standard XIB files as well.